# How to Install the latest version of VirtualBox For Ubuntu 21.04?

Tags: virtualbox, repository, 21.04

I did use Synaptic to install VirtualBox but I found its older version, so I want to know How to Install the latest version of VirtualBox For Ubuntu 21.04?

Is there an official repository that I can add to get the latest updates of VirtualBox?

Comment: I have much better luck getting VBox from Ubuntu Software than from VirtualBox.org. The version seems a little older but always works better for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you would like to get VirtualBox straight from Oracle, this is how you can do it:

0. Open Terminal (if it's not already open)
1. Open the `/etc/apt/sources.list` file using a text editor of your choice. For example:

   ```
   sudo vi /etc/apt/sources.list
   ```
2. Add the repository (perhaps at the very bottom of the file):

   ```
   deb [arch=amd64] https://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian hirsute contrib
   ```
3. Download and add the requisite key for apt:

   ```
   wget -q https://www.virtualbox.org/download/oracle_vbox_2016.asc -O- | sudo apt-key add -
   ```

   The fingerprint for this key is:

   ```
   B9F8 D658 297A F3EF C18D  5CDF A2F6 83C5 2980 AECF
   Oracle Corporation (VirtualBox archive signing key) <info@virtualbox.org>
   ```
4. Update apt:

   ```
   sudo apt update
   ```
5. Install VirtualBox:

   ```
   sudo apt install virtualbox-6.1
   ```

Source: [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads)

Comment: @Sharif Even better put the line in a new file in the directory `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/`

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: times change; this worked on ubuntu 22.04, with a warning: ``Warning: apt-key is deprecated. Manage keyring files in trusted.gpg.d instead (see apt-key(8)).``