# How to install the latest version of VirtualBox (via GUI)?

Tags: software-installation, virtualbox, 22.04

### Background

After a day's work with a Windows 10 guest running on an Ubuntu (Jammy) host, suddenly the guest started to crash, cf. e.g.:

- https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/virtualbox/+bug/1988473 (**VirtualBox 6.1.34 guests crash with kernel 5.15.0-47**)
- [On Ubuntu 22.04 with VirtualBox, Windows 10 guest won't run anymore](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1427683/on-ubuntu-22-04-with-virtualbox-windows-10-guest-wont-run-anymore)
- [Ubuntu 22.04 seems to freeze in Virtualbox 6.1 on Windows 11](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1415045/ubuntu-22-04-seems-to-freeze-in-virtualbox-6-1-on-windows-11)
- https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=105847&sid=35f878b51d1b8d993242194fe4ce2b2c&start=15
- https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=106954 (*"Update VirtualBox to 6.1.**36** to get support for later kernels."*)

Perhaps upgrading to the latest version of VirtualBox, i.e. from **`6.1.34_Ubuntu r150636`** to **`6.1.38`** will solve this issue - hopefully!

---

### First (unsuccessful) attempt to install latest version via GUI

In an attempt to install the [latest version of VirtualBox](https://itsfoss.com/install-virtualbox-ubuntu/), following the instructions on https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads, the first step of [adding a line to `/etc/apt/sources.list`](https://askubuntu.com/questions/197564/how-do-i-add-a-line-to-my-etc-apt-sources-list) (via GUI, i.e. Software & Updates → *Other Software* → *Add...*) already caused a first hiccup as

```
deb [arch=amd64 signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/oracle-virtualbox-2016.gpg] https://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian jammy contrib
```

would leave the *Add Source* button **grayed out**. Removing `[…]` would make the button clickable, but seems to be the wrong thing to do. Or at least might necessitate further steps in the GUI, around adding the key, but I can't seem to find and figure out right now.

Unfortunately, https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu#Adding_Extra_Repositories does not fully explain.

Help appreciated.

---

Related link(s):

- [How to Install the latest version of VirtualBox For Ubuntu 21.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1338997/how-to-install-the-latest-version-of-virtualbox-for-ubuntu-21-04)
- https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu#Adding_Extra_Repositories

Comment: Why are you adding sources? `virtualbox` is in the `universe` repo.  Just run `sudo apt update` and then run `sudo apt install virtualbox`. You don't need to add any sources. You only would need to enable `universe` if you previously disabled it. You probably don't need the "latest version". Don't chase down "latest versions" unless you absolutely need them.  The latest is not the greatest. See: [Why don't the Ubuntu repositories have the latest versions of software?](https://askubuntu.com/q/151283)

Comment: @Nmath Updated the question ("background").

Comment: Your update doesn't answer my question or address any of my suggestions or comments. Did you mean to @ someone else?

Comment: @Nmath It does: https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=106954 // *Perhaps upgrading to the latest version of VirtualBox, i.e. from 6.1.34_Ubuntu r150636 to 6.1.38 will solve this issue - hopefully!*

Comment: Have you tried to download the latest `.deb` file from: https://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/6.1.38/virtualbox-6.1_6.1.38-153438~Ubuntu~jammy_amd64.deb and then install it using `sudo apt install /path/to/the_downloaded_virtualbox.deb`?

Comment: @BeastOfCaerbannog: Yes and no: I tried simply double-clicking etc and have not yet run the command, which you suggest, in terminal (cf. https://askubuntu.com/questions/264292/how-do-i-install-virtualboxs-deb-package#comment2486609_264295). But happy to do so soon. At the moment, using a different laptop as a workaround. Question: if I ran the command you suggest, would it install the deb alongside the existing VirtualBox installation (without any conflict / issues :-)?

Comment: @nuttyaboutnatty Hmmm... There could potentially be some conflict, so I suggest that you first uninstall your currently installed version and install the `.deb` after that. After all, if you find that the `.deb` doesn't work for you, you can remove it and install the previous package through `apt` again.

Comment: In the end, I did it via **command line** (not via GUI), following instructions here (method 3): https://itsfoss.com/install-virtualbox-ubuntu/. (Note that this method is itself slightly deprecated, but still works, cf. https://itsfoss.com/apt-key-deprecated/. Good enough: it works. Well, after running `sudo /sbin/vboxconfig` to get the existing *.vdi's working again... Oh well...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I did it via command line (not via GUI), following instructions here (method 3, *Install VirtualBox using Oracle’s repository*): https://itsfoss.com/install-virtualbox-ubuntu/. (Note that this method is itself slightly deprecated, but still works, cf. https://itsfoss.com/apt-key-deprecated. Good enough: it works. Well, after running `sudo /sbin/vboxconfig` to get the existing *.vdi's working again... Oh well...)

<sub>I know, should not only post links here, but also appropriately cited content...</sub>

Answer (score 1):

Give the following a try. I know that your question is requesting how to do this via GUI, but I think the following will get you where you want to go. It just isn't via GUI.

```bash
wget -qO- https://www.virtualbox.org/download/oracle_vbox_2016.asc | sudo tee /etc/apt/keyrings/virtualbox.asc
echo "deb [arch=amd64 signed-by=/etc/apt/keyrings/virtualbox.asc] https://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian jammy contrib" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list
sudo apt update
sudo apt install virtualbox-6.1
```

Answer (score 0):

I uninstalled the Ubuntu package of Virtualbox 6.x and went for a direct download from the Virtualbox website: https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads

Unfortunately I experienced similar problems until I installed the now current version 7.0.12. That one gave a better error message stating

```
VM Name: win11

VD: Backend 'VBoxIsoMaker' does not support async I/O (VERR_NOT_SUPPORTED).
VirtualBox can't operate in VMX root mode. Please disable the KVM kernel
extension, recompile your kernel and reboot (VERR_VMX_IN_VMX_ROOT_MODE).
```

Indeed qemu / kvm was installed in parallel all the time. I am wondering why just now this would create an issue. Since then I am trying to uninstall kvm but am not there yet.